# how to move divs more freely even when they are aligned to the center of the webpage

Tags: html, css

i have three divs aligned in the center of the webpage as shown in the image below and i dont know how i can move them more downwards without using margin or padding
i want to add more space on top of the divs so i can add an image on top of them, is there away to accomplish this using flexbox which i already am using

here is the html file

```
<main>
    <div class="who">
        <h1><img class ="who-we" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/who.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>Who We Are</h2>
        <p class="who-info">DSPR is an ecumenical and Church – related organization which is an integral part of the
Middle East Council of Churches (MECC).
It was founded following the 1950 Arab Israeli War and the creation of the Palestine refugee
problem.
        </p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="what">
        <h1><img class ="work" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/what.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>What We Do</h2>
        <p class="what-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat</p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>

    <div class="where">
        <h1><img class="jordan" src="https://dsprme.org/lib/images/where.png?222"></h1>
        <h2>Where We Work</h2>
        <p class="where-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori</p>
        <a class = "Read-more" href="dspr.html">Read More</a>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the css file

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    color: #222;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

header{
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul li a{
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

li a:hover::before, li a:hover::after{
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}

li a::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FCAE1E;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
li a::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FCAE1E;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    height:calc(100vh - 100px);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


.who{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.what{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.where{ 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.who-we{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.work{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.jordan{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.who-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.Read-more{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.what-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.where-info{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Vtf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier getting another two divisions wrapping up the Img portion and the other three divisions.

```
[is this the structure you want.Later you can adjust the image ][1]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).